# What to do about a user trying to change the meaning of the SRS tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

The [srs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/srs) tag is defined, in its Wiki Excerpt, as being for questions related to "Software Requirement Specification". It does not have many questions: currently 38 (but some of these are likely mis-tagged – *vide infra*).

However, a [new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17679565/winlin?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) is actively adding (or attempting to add) this tag to questions about "Simple Realtime Server". In fact, this user has attempted to re-define the tag with suggested edits to the Wiki and Wiki Excerpt.

The latter ([which I came across during review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30589781)) has already been rejected (thanks to some help from an SOCVR regular) but [the suggestion for the Wiki itself is still pending](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30589780)<sup>1</sup>. Note that there is currently no main Wiki text for the *original* SRS meaning.

What should be done about this? As there are still only a few posts, should we disambiguate these two meanings into separate, more explicit tags? And, if so, what shall we name them? Or, should the "first-claimed" meaning reign supreme, and the attempts at redefinition be simply rejected (possibly with an appropriate communication to the new user)?

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, since posting this question, a moderator has now rejected the suggested edit to the main Wiki.

Comment: If questions associated with the original specification are likely on-topic for the site, it looks like we need a new tag for the potential new use. *Post scriptum*, thank you for teaching me a new Latin phrase.

Comment: Considering there are only 38 questions for [[tag:srs]] it might seem better to have 2 disambiguated tags, as the impact isn't that high. If the original tag was more cemented, then that would be less viable without a lot of effort fro curators or moderator/staff intervention.

Comment: @Larnu Sounds very reasonable. Any suggestions as to the tag names?

Comment: "Software Requirement Specification" is 34 characters, so [software-requirement-specification] seems reasonable. "Simple Realtime Server" is only 22, so [simple-realtime-server] is a no-brainer.

Comment: I just noticed, that new user appears to be affiliated with the new technology they are trying make the tag about.

Comment: I would consider all those edits as spam, because that user is the maintainer of the SRS framework and those edits are done to increase the visibility of that framework.

Comment: vide infra == see below

Comment: @Tom Don't always assume bad faith in new users.

Comment: Acronyms can be so overloaded. When I saw SRS my first thought was "Spaced Repetition System"

Comment: @ughStackExchange Where is that "always" coming from? You don't know me, so stop assuming stuff.

Comment: Is "Software Requirement Specification" even on topic?

Comment: When I saw this post listed on the sidebar, I thought of at least three things I've seen "SRS" used to stand for commonly, none of which have anything to do with either programming or each other.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yeah - for sure, there are other issues going on here, Which is kinda why I raised it on Mata.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking:

- If you come across a series of incorrect edits from the same user, you need to flag one of the questions where the edit attempt was made. Pick a custom flag and explain the issue to a moderator. Provide links to other incorrect edits.
- As for changing the meaning of a tag and tag wiki, that isn't allowed before prior meta discussion and community consensus. Such edits need a rollback. If the tag is ambiguous it should also be brought up on meta for tag renaming or removal.

As for this specific issue of edits, the user is now aware, changes have been rejected and the matter seems to be resolved.

*However*, a tag for a software requirement specification might be borderline off-topic. While project management is apparently no longer listed as explicitly off-topic, questions regarding such are more suited for https://pm.stackexchange.com/. At any rate, "SRS" is as far as I know not a well-established abbreviation. The tag should probably be renamed or removed, if someone wants to make a separate post about that.

Comment: Looking at the most upvoted questions with that tag: Either they are about how to write an SRS/what they should contain, or it is about a person having an SRS which they have to follow (I believe). First kind is offtopic, second kind can simply have the tag removed (this is ignoring the decent number of question where the tag is misused). It might be worth to clean up the current tag and then maybe add it as a synonym for the Simple Realtime Server tag that should be created.

Answer (score 41):

I'm the guy who request to update the tag [srs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/srs), I'm sorry if did something wrong.

[SRS](https://github.com/ossrs/srs) is an open-source project and I'm starting to build the Q&A for developers, so I need a tag like srs or similar. Let me give more information.

I started SRS in 2013, as Simple RTMP Server, a open-source live streaming server. At first, I only wanted to build a small open-soure project to solve a small problem, say RTMP server.

After about 8 years, SRS supports more than RTMP/HTTP-FLV/HLS/HDS, it supports WebRTC for video chat, transmux live streaming with RTC, SRT/GB/DASH protocols, DVR and Clusters. The end-to-end latency change from 10s(HLS) 1-3s(RTMP/HTTP-FLV) to 200ms(WebRTC), so I changed the name from RTMP to Realtime server, SRS(Simple Realtime Server).

SRS is used by lots of live streaming and WebRTC developers all over the world, and one of active open-source media-server. Although we got a few of stars in Github, but we're a starter to build the developer community.

We wrote a set of wikis and issues, and there is a simple FAQ about SRS, but we need a better Q&A community. I firmly confirm that Stack Overflow is the best Q&A community, so I want to start to build the Q&A of SRS here.

Because we used GitHub wiki/issues, so right now there is few questions in Stack Overflow. I have answered some questions, and need a tag for these questions. If the tag srs is not a proper one, maybe I should use a new tag like srs-server? Or another tag name? It's fine for me.

Appreciate for any suggestions, thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. I noted a tag name in a comment to the question: [simple-realtime-server]. No need to abbreviate. No need for a TLA. Just call it what it is. As you build your Q&A here, some things to keep in mind: the basics, like [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), plus those around support: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support); [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Roger that, thank you very much.

Comment: The information given is all well and good, but none of that justifies hijacking an existing tag (for future reference, if nothing else). The only real justifications one can have for taking over another tag is if the original tag meaning doesn't belong on the site in the first place (which you can potentially argue for here) or if your meaning is already what most questions using the tag are actually about on [so] (but this doesn't appear to be the case). And both of those would require discussing it on Meta *before* making any edits.

Comment: A note on tags: Tags are reactive, not proactive. If people ask questions about a topic, then a tag can be created for that topic. A tag can't get created before there are questions (removing a tag from all questions is the exact way to delete a tag on [so]). If a tag is often misused, then its meaning is changed to fit however it's used (if that usage is on topic, or the tag is removed or replaced by less ambiguous alternatives). The only requirement for people asking questions about your project here is that those questions follow the general rules (clear, not too broad, etc.).

Comment: @NotThatGuy considering that the tag itself is ambiguous and its usage didn't match the description, forcing one is warranted.

Comment: @Braiam The wiki says it's about Software Requirement Specification, and about half the questions match this usage (and the other half is a mix of... I'm not quite sure what). A 50%+ hit rate is a good argument against changing its meaning to anything else, but only a 50% hit rate is perhaps a good argument for renaming the tag. But, then again, only 20 or so questions need to be retagged to fix the problem. But, then again, again, I'm not sure questions about Software Requirement Specifications even belong on [so], as has already been said (but that's a different discussion).

Comment: The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRS#Software) lists only some meanings, and there is no `Simple Realtime Server`, because I have no permission to edit it for my ip is blocked, hahaha, you know that's because I'm in China, :) PS: The tag [simple-realtime-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/simple-realtime-server) is not available right now, need 1500 reputation to use this tag in a question, I will do that when I got enough reputation, and resign tag to all questions about it.

Comment: @Winlin I did create the tag, you should now be able to suggest edits adding it to question, and to suggest adding a tag wiki/excerpt.

Comment: @MegaIng Thanks a lot. It works now. ^____^